# Magento 2 custom SOAP Api returns error

Tags: magento-2.1, custom, soap-api-v1

I am trying to create new custom SOAP API but it returns following error "**SoapClient::SoapClient(): $wsdl must be string or null**"

etc/webapi.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
<route method="GET" url="/V1/mageplaza-helloworld/posts">
    <service class="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Api\PostManagementInterface" method="getPost"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Api/PostManagementInterface:

```
<?php
  namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Api;

  interface PostManagementInterface {

    public function getPost();
 } 
?>
```

etc/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Api\PostManagementInterface" type="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostManagement"/>
 </config>
```

Model/PostManagement.php

```
<?php
 namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model;

 class PostManagement {

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getPost()
{
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom-api.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info("Did't generated the session id");

    return 'api GET return the';
    }
 }
```

Api request:

```
    $name = array("param"=>"Jim");

    $wsdlUrl = new SoapClient("http://127.0.0.1/magento201/soap/default?wsdl&services=mageplazaHelloWorldPostManagementV1");
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    try{
        $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
        $soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
        $soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
        $soapResponse = $soapClient->mageplazaHelloWorldPostManagementV1GetPost($name);
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump($soapResponse);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Exception Error:------".$e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: It means that you WSDL route was not acceded or working, It couldn't connect to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is referred to $soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl); and $wsdlUrl is not a string but a SoapClient. I mean you are using two SoapClients when you need only one.

Try to change this line:

```
 $wsdlUrl = new SoapClient("http://127.0.0.1/magento201/soap/default?wsdl&services=mageplazaHelloWorldPostManagementV1");
```

into this one:

```
$wsdlUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/magento201/soap/default?wsdl&services=mageplazaHelloWorldPostManagementV1";
```